# How to add a column with the corresponding day?

Tags: excel

I want to create data that ranges from 01/01/2004  00:30:00  to 31/12/2004  23:30:00  with time step half hourly. I would like also to add a column with just the corresponding day using excel for example:

```
        01/01/2004  00:30:00      1
         01/01/2004  01:00:00      1 
         01/02/2004  00:30:00      2 
         31/12/2004  23:30:00     365
```

I tried to make it but I wonder why from cretin date the time step was changing from:

```
                 03/01/2004 **01:30**
                 03/01/2004 **02:00**
                  to
                 03/01/2004 **02:29**
                 03/01/2004 **02:59**
                  03/01/2004 03:29
                 03/01/2004 03:59
```

Any help?

Comment: weather the source data's time is in half hour steps from 00 and 30, or 29 and 59 would not affect the answer I gave below because the answer ignores the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date is in cell A1, the following formula will work:

```
=INT(A1)-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0)
```

The `Int` removes the time from the date, and then it subtracts December 31st of the previous year to produce the number of days that have passed in the year.

Answer (score 0):

For the step, use formula
`=A1+1/48` and copy down.

Comment: This formula adds 30 minutes to the date.